# How to find index deep in javascript array and return other part of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, find

I want to return `rj: Object` below, and I have an index key to match, `kid: 1`.  What's the best/fastest way of doing considerg the main `Object` can contain > 10k items?

```
Object
 coord: MM.Coordinate
 data: Object
 geometry: Object
 properties: Object
   kid: 1            <== index id
   rj: Object        <== object i want
   __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
element: HTMLDivElement
location: MM.Location
touch: true
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: How does this main object look like? Is this object the main? or is this just an entry of the main object?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's from Chrome console. Top `Object` is main, yes. So I'll have 10k's of those. Then the unique identifier is deep in `Object[properties[kid]]`, and the object I actually want is its next door neighbour.

Comment: Is the main object sorted somehow? Do you need to find more than one item by its unique id?

Comment: @Bergi I need to find many of these, so performance is an issue. But there's no index - unless `kid` counts as index. I mean, that would be great! ;)

Comment: the main object is an array? how does the collection look like from main? Also, is it assured that all entries have `properties`,`kid` and `rj` properties?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer actually, the `markers` array contains this top `Object` along with others. Sorry. But yes, they're all identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find many objects, you can build a lookup table. Iterate over your collection of main objects, and store them in an key-value-map (simple object) by their identifier:

```
var mainsByKid = {}; // if the keys are integers (and not sparse), use an array
for (var i=0; i<mains.length; i++) {
     var main = mains[i],
         key = main.properties.kid; // must be unique
     mainsByKid[key] = main;
}
```

Now you can simply access your object by

```
mainsByKid[1];
```

Comment: a for-in loop should be used on objects, unless the object in question is an array.

Comment: Until we don't know how the collection really looks, I can only assume it is an array. Had upvoted your comments on the question already :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I need. Turns out mapbox.js which I'm working with already had implement basically the exact same thing. Thanks again.